# importing decoreators.py in top-level directory django project

Tags: django, python-decorators

Is there any way to create `decorators.py` file in top-level folder of the project in Django so many applications can use it?

If the file is in top-level dir and I try to import it to `myapp/views.py` by:

```
from ..decorators import student_required, teacher_required
```

I get an error:

```
    from ..decorators import student_required, teacher_required
ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

However when importing this way:

```
from .decorators import student_required, teacher_required
```

The output is:

```
    from .decorators import student_required, teacher_required
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myapp.decorators'
```

I need to use this decorators in `myapp1, myapp2, myapp3` and I don't want to populate the same file over and over again. Is there any quick workaround for this? How can I point to the `decorators.py` properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to import it is a path to it. So you could put it in project root and just run:

`from decorators import whatever`

I'd advise against this because of potential namespacing issues.

Second option is to put it in the django project folder, so you could do:

`from <myproject>.decorators import whatever`

I usually call my main project `config` and then have a `core` app alongside it for stuff that is to be used in other apps, so I'd put it there for my setup and run.

`from core.decorators import whatever`

Or you could just create another module in the root called `core` (or anything else) - this is just a directory containing an `__init__.py` file, and achieve the same effect.

If it's a big project, you should probably namespace the whole thing too, but that's a different consideration :)

Addendum: If imports in general are problematic, you're either missing an `__init__.py` somewhere, or your `PYTHONPATH` isn't configured correctly.